# How can I convert a std::string to std::vector?

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I have some code which I need to serialize a vector into bytes, then send it to a server. Later on, the the server replies with bytes and I need to serialize it back into a vector.

I have managed to serialize into bytes okay, but converting back into a vector is getting the wrong values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v = {1, 2, 3};
    std::cout << "Original vector: " << std::endl;
    for (auto i : v) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::string str((char *)v.data(), sizeof(v[0])*v.size());
    std::cout << "Vector memory as string: " << std::endl << str << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Convert the string back to vector: " << std::endl;
    auto rV = std::vector<double>(&str[0], &str[str.size()]);
    for (auto i : rV){
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
Original vector: 
1 2 3 
Vector memory as string: 
�?@@
Convert the string back to vector: 
0 0 0 0 0 0 -16 63 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 64 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 64
```

What is going wrong with my conversion from a string to a vector, and how can I fix it?

[Here is a link to run the code.](https://godbolt.org/z/7zbhYv6qf)

Comment: So, you want each element of the vector to be altogether displayed like `1 2 3` as a string?

Comment: @RohanBari Thats correct

Comment: I would recommend using some serialization library. IIRC, Boost.Serialization can work with vectors.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thanks for the recommendation, I will look into it. I am brand new to C++ so every problem I face is brand new to me.

Comment: If your clients and servers have the same architecture — same sized primitives, same endian-ness, same floating point representation (e.g., IEEE 754) — then this approach is ducky.  If the clients and servers have a non-homogenous architecture, this approach will be a problem.  Speaking from experience, as my company's product went from DEC Alpha to DEC Alpha and Intel IA-64 (Itanium) mixed environment.

Comment: You will also run into trouble if `double` on your platform has alignment restrictions, as `str.data()` is not guaranteed to be aligned correctly

Comment: Why not simply "send" the raw vector data directly instead? Passing e.g. `reinterpret_cast<char*>(v.data())` directly to the function sending the data?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am using gRPC and the function only accepts std::string

Comment: @Caleth Can you expand what you mean? Is the data held by std::string not contiguous? I am new to C++

Comment: @TomMcLean there are platforms where `double`s *must* start on addresses that are multiples of 8, the CPU can't load them otherwise

Comment: @Eljay Do you know of ways to improve this approach? The server basically converts a byte string into a numpy array so I can use `numpy.frombuffer` and specify the 'endian-ness'

Comment: gRPC is built on top of protocol buffers, last I checked you could define your own message types

Comment: @Caleth Thanks, I will look into that. Someone else built the gRPC server and instead of using `repeated float32 data` or something along that, they just have a `bytes` field. I might change it.

Comment: Since you control both ends (both the client and server), you just need to be mindful.  Since what you have works, it works.  Which is okay, because *good enough* is good enough.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks for your help, I will keep it as-is for the moment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this

```
std::vector<double>((double*)str.data(), (double*)(str.data() + str.size()));
```

Basically the same as your code, but I've added some casts. In your version the chars get converted directly into doubles (as if you had written `rV[0] = str[0]` etc) and the vector is `sizeof(double)` times too big.